# Credential Security Android App

Tags: android, encryption, confidentiality

I build an Android Application, that needs some password and some Identiy information, for tests I just put them in String variables, Now I am looking for a way to Encrypt them, Any ideas ( Without Hash code ).

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

`AccountManager` can helps you to store in a secure place, username and password of your application:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html